# Convert a text file with a particular format into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas and thus I wanted to know if I can convert my text file with a particular format into a Pandas data frame. Below is my text file format

```
"FACT"|"FSYM"|"POSITION"|"INDIRECT_OPTIONS"|"REPORT"|"SOURCE"|"COMMENTS"|
"ABCX"|"VVG1"|2800000|760000|2022-11-03|"A"|"INCLUDES CAR"|0
```

I wanted to convert this format in Pandas with same columns and values as separated by | sign. That is my data frame columns will be FACT, FYSM,POSITION, and so on.

I am trying below code but it does not give me the desired output.

```
def convert_factset_file_to_dataframe(test_case_name, file_name):
    data = pd.read_csv("{}/output/Float_Ingestion_files/{}/{}.txt".format(str(parentDir), test_case_name, file_name), sep=',')

    print(data)
```

It is printing as follows. Just adding the index.

```
    "FACT"|"FSYM"|"POSITION"|"INDIRECT_OPTIONS"|"REPORT"|"SOURCE"|"COMMENTS"|
0    "ABCX"|"VVG1"|2800000|760000|2022-11-03|"A"|"INCLUDES CAR"|0
```

Is there any other way of converting my text file format to a data frame besides reading it as a CSV? Or I need to incorporate some changes in the code?

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `read_csv(..... sep='|')` instead of `read_csv(..... sep=',')`? The seperator is the `|` sign as you say, not the `,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the argument `sep` (as stated in Thomas' comment).

```
data = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep="|")
```

For more information, see the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
df.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t')
```

To use a specific encoding (e.g. 'utf-8') use the encoding argument:

```
df.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo and should call

```py
data = pd.read_csv(
    "{}/output/Float_Ingestion_files/{}/{}.txt".format(
        str(parentDir), test_case_name, file_name
    ),
    sep="|",  # <<<<<<<<< don't choose the comma here, choose `|`
)
```

That is, just change the argument for the separator to be the `|` sign